# Inspect shows record but still get undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a report screen, and doing my relationship lookups for the associated data.  For some reason I keep getting errors when trying to get an attribute of the relationship, yet .inspect shows the information plain as day.

```
orders_detail.products_cost.flavor.inspect
```

outputs

```
 #<Flavor flavor_id: 13, identifier: "BR", description: "Blue Razz">
```

however

```
orders_detail.products_cost.flavor.flavor_id
```

outputs

```
undefined method `flavor_id' for nil:NilClass
```

models

```
class OrdersDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "orders_detail"
    belongs_to :orders_header, foreign_key: 'order_header_id'
    belongs_to :address 
    belongs_to :products_cost
    belongs_to :machine, foreign_key: 'machine_id'
end



class ProductsCost < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = "products_cost"
        belongs_to :product
        belongs_to :size
        belongs_to :units_of_measure, foreign_key: "uom_id"
        belongs_to :flavor


        validates :product_id, :presence => true
        validates :flavor_id, :presence => true
        validates :size_id, :presence => true
        validates :uom_id, :presence => true

end


class Flavor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_costs
end
```

Comment: what does `orders_detail.products_cost.flavor.identifier` shows?

Comment: undefined method `identifier' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Is it AR object? Did you change the default primary key if yes?

Comment: Its attaching to a database that certainly doesnt conform to rails standards, I have had to declare lots of self.table names, and foreign key specifications, but most everything works, except a few of these.

Comment: What if you do `Flavor.first.flavor_id`? Will it as well throw an error?

Comment: Also, what `Flavor.first.attributes` outputs?

Comment: Flavor.first.flavor_id = Flavor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `flavors`.* FROM `flavors`  ORDER BY `flavors`.`flavor_id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => 1


and


Flavor.first.attributes
  Flavor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `flavors`.* FROM `flavors`  ORDER BY `flavors`.`flavor_id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => {"flavor_id"=>1, "identifier"=>"Unf", "description"=>"Unflavored"}

Comment: then it is strange at least for me.. Sanity check: are you 1000% sure you are calling `flavor_id` on existing `flavor`?

Comment: Turns out that one of the records was linking to a bad flavor Id... you figured it out :)  Post an answer and I'll happily mark it as such!

Comment: glad it's solved! :) will add an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in comments to question, having that each of below works as expected:

```
Flavor.first.flavor_id
Flavor.first.attributes
```

means, that attributes reading is not broken. The only reason is that as per error: you are referencing bad/invalid/inexistent object `flavor`.